# How to associate mat-label and mat-select when mat-label is outside of mat-form-field (to make it accessible)

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I'm using Angular and Material version 11.
I want to have a form select with the label outside the form box at all times:

[image: example of wanted outcome]

I read that I should just put the mat-label outside of the mat-form-field like this:

```
<mat-label for="filterColumn">{{'choose_column'|translate}}</mat-label>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-select id="filterColumn" placeholder="Select column to filter" [(ngModel)]="data.filteredColumn">
        <mat-option [value]="column.label" *ngFor="let column of data.displayColumns">
             {{column.label | translate}}
        </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This works, but how can I make sure the label knows it belongs to the select box? I want to be able to click on the label and the select field will be focused. aka I want it to be still accessible.
I tried already by putting for="filterColumn" inside mat-label and id="filterColumn" inside mat-select (as you can see in the code) to let them make the connection, but this does not seem to work. I also tried to do it with an ordinary  but to no avail.

I noticed that in the generated code  is rendered completely different inside mat-form-field or outside. If it is inside mat-form-field it transforms into a label. If mat-label is put outside the mat-form-field, it keeps being a mat-label and doesn't transform into a label tag.

To illustrate: here is an example of mat-label inside mat-select (with same code as above but only the mat-label is placed inside mat-form-field and I removed for and id to let angular generate it.)
[image: generated code when mat-label is inside mat-select]

Here is the example of generation with my piece of code:
[image: generation of code where you can see that mat-label doesn't transform into label]

So is there a way to be able to display the label as shown in the picture and be it accessible while using angular material (v.11)?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `htmlFor` which behaves the same way as a standard `for` attribute.

Or I believe you can still use `attr.for` if you are using older Angular, but the above is the latest way.

```html
<!--change the `for` attribute on the label to `htmlFor` -->
<mat-label htmlFor="filterColumn">{{'choose_column'|translate}}</mat-label>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-select id="filterColumn" placeholder="Select column to filter" [(ngModel)]="data.filteredColumn">
        <mat-option [value]="column.label" *ngFor="let column of data.displayColumns">
             {{column.label | translate}}
        </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! htmlFor and attr.for indeed transformed it into a <label> tag, so I'm already a step further. But I still can't click the label so the selectbox gets focus, so it still doesn't seem to be accessible unfortunately

Comment: @marijke hmm, that is the way to associate the label and that should make it focusable when clicking the label. Could you set a fiddle up and I will have a proper look for you and help you sort. Just a minimal fiddle that demos the problem.

Comment: I've never made a fiddle or a plnkr. So I first tried to make a fiddle but I coudn't make it work and then I tried a plnkr (because I read that is better when using Angular), but I can't seem to add the MatSelectModule and MatFormFieldsModule to the AppModule. This is my plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/oun1iJz1MyZ9CKBe?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1 . when I try to add those modules it says it cannot find the modules even though I put Material in the package.json

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on trying to solve it using [attr.for], but did this instead:

```
<mat-label (click)="inputCtrl.open()">Label</mat-label>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #inputCtrl ...
```

you could also use .focus if you want to just focus it.