# Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT> Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I'm receiving the following error from Angular Material when I try to use a `<mat-label>` element inside a simple `<mat-form-field>`:

[image: Chrome console error]

Here is the problematic code:

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
  <mat-select [value]="stateService.currentYear.toString()"
              (valueChange)="onYearChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years"
                [value]="year">
      {{year}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is the rendered component:

[image]

The component is fully functional and the label is properly growing and shrinking when selecting and deselecting the widget. The problem is with this error popping in my developer console, which I want to discard (does not look very professional).

I tried to assign some ids, use different semantic, with no results so far.

Any idea on how to clear this error?

Edit (31/12/2023): My chrome's browser console also logs this error in the official select documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: Where is the error coming from?  Your browser? Your IDE? Some kind of lint/test?

Comment: It is in the browser's console, in chrome

Comment: Can you share your definition of "years"?

Comment: The years variable is an array of string: `string[]`

Comment: I mean looking at [the Material docs for a select menu](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/select/overview) you seem to be doing it correctly. What does the rendered HTML show, what `id` is the `for` referencing on the label?  Also, [possibly check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76688838/79677)

Comment: Thank you for your links, although this answer does not solve my issue... It looks like it is coming from Chrome (sadly enough). I'm having the same error on the official input documentation page: https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann is there any ts code you've written to modify the HTML dynamically? If yes, please share.

Comment: No there is not, it appears to be the default behavior for Angular material

Comment: Have a look at what is actually getting generated by turning on the "show user-agent shadow DOM" option under "elements", so you can see the "real" elements that angular/material built. Material hides all the details in custom elements, each with their own shadow DOM, which dev tools will hide unless explicitly told to show.

Comment: You should submit a bug report in the library repo

Comment: With the default Chrome devtools settings, I don't get any error messages on that [official input documentation page](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) you linked to, and can confirm that the `for` attribute values match the appropriate `id` attribute values. Either they've fixed it, or it may be something to do with a devtools extension you have running.

Comment: Hi Sean, did you try this one: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue as you with the unwanted errors in Chrome, do you have any update on this?

Comment: Still on it. Would love to find a fix

Comment: Opened an issue on Angular Material Github: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack to clear my browser console. Using a directive made it easy to fix the whole app at once. Applies to the mat-form-field elements.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

/**
 * Prevent our angular material floating label selects
 * inside mat-form-field from firing unwanted errors
 */
@Directive({selector: "mat-form-field"})
export class RemoveMatFormFieldLabelForDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  // Constructor

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  // After view init

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const label = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("label");
    if (label && label.getAttribute("for")) {

      // If we just remove the for attribute, a warning message still remains
      label.removeAttribute("for");

      // Nesting a fictive input inside the label fixed the problem for me
      const fictiveInput = document.createElement("input");
      fictiveInput.style.display = "none";
      fictiveInput.setAttribute("name", "fictive-input");
      label.appendChild(fictiveInput);

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a mat-select is not an [labelable element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) and the "for" of the label indicate the "mat-select "id"

We can remove it using a directive. If you use the selector mat-select only need import the directive in the module or in the component if you're using standalone components

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select',
})
export class RemoveFor implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const label=this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')
      if (label.length && label[0].getAttribute('for'))
          label[0].removeAttribute('for')
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: This helped a lot to find a hack for my problem. But I still had a warning with this method, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select[removeFor]'
})
export class RemoveForDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const label = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector('label');
      if (label && label.getAttribute('for')) {
        label.removeAttribute('for');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The selector is specified as `mat-select[removeFor]` to apply the directive only to mat-select elements with the removeFor attribute.

The querySelector method is used to select the label associated with the mat-select element.
If a label with a for attribute is found, the for attribute is removed using removeAttribute.

Make sure to add this directive to the declarations array of your module to use it in your application.

Additionally, ensure that the directive is applied to the mat-select elements where you want to remove the for attribute from the associated label.

Now, you can use the removeFor attribute on mat-select elements in your HTML templates to apply the directive:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select an option" removeFor>
    <mat-option value="pizza">Pizza</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="pasta">Pasta</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="burger">Burger</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try it out and update you

Comment: This helped a lot to find a hack for my problem. But I still had a warning with this method, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue, and found your thread. I ended up using a mat-placeholder instead of a mat-label.  I'm using angular material version 16.

```
    <mat-form-field class="selectControl">
       <mat-placeholder><mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="info" matTooltip="Foo" color="primary">info</mat-icon> &nbsp;Label Here:</mat-placeholder>
       <mat-select [formControl]="matSelect" class="position-Select" (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let foo of foos" [value]="object.id">
                {{ object.name }}
           </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I'm having an issue with the mat-form-field being 16px padding on the top and bottom that makes the mat-select not be the same size vertically as the other mat-form-fields, but this got past the label for issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have troubles using the <mat-placeholder> component. Are you importing `MatLegacyFormFieldModule`? I am using Angular material 16.0.3

Answer (score -1):

`<input matInput style="width: 0px;">`

Very annoying issue. I added this line in the mat-form-field and the error disappeared.

Comment: I just tested it and the error goes away with using <input matInput style="width: 0px;">. The error does not appear when it is just a text input. This error appears only when it is a select list. I have spent hours trying to hack this and this seems like a good hack so far.

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann The full code snippet: <mat-form-field color="accent"> <mat-label>Year</mat-label> <input matInput style="width: 0px;"><mat-select [value]="stateService.currentYear.toString()" (valueChange)="onYearChange($event)"> <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year"> {{year}} </mat-option> </mat-select> </mat-form-field>

Comment: The error indeed goes away, but I am not satisfied with this answer as the output element is bugged using this hack. Thank you for your input

Answer (score -1):

So far this does seem to be the only hack that works. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<mat-form-field class="selectControl">
   <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
   <input matInput style="width: 0px;">
   <mat-select [formControl]="matSelect" class="position-Select" (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let foo of foos" [value]="object.id">
            {{ object.name }}
       </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The output element has a bugged appearance using this hack.. Thanks for your input!

Comment: mat-form-field may need this [floatLabel]="'always'". This way you can specify different text for placeholder and label itself.

Comment: Adding floatLabel seems to fix my problem, but then when you click on the `<select>` the behavior is buggy (does not open well). It is actually better to keep the error.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Make sure you have floatlabel, <label> and place holder specified. I just did not like how the place holder became label and threw error. I also not sure how all this code affects accessibility conserns.

Answer (score -1):

By adding a hidden  element, this error can be avoided.
Temporary solutions, informal.

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
  <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
  <select id="year-select" style="display: none;"></select>  <!-- add this line -->
  <mat-select id="year-select" [value]="stateService.currentYear.toString() (valueChange)="onYearChange($event)"> <!-- add the same `id` attribute as above -->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year"> 
      {{year}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Found this solution here -> [feat(material/form-field): add MatLabel input property to change use of html](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27241)